# PHP looping table columns

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I have a salary table like this:

[image]

and I want to display the data like this

[image]

how do i display it with foreach on PHP?

edit:
this is my example data

```
{
        [
            'id': 1,
            'salary_name': 'Basic Salary',
            'salary_type': 'Allowance',
            'salary_amount': 5000,
        ],
        [
            'id': 2,
            'salary_name': 'Health Benefits',
            'salary_type': 'Allowance',
            'salary_amount': 500,
        ],
        [
            'id': 3,
            'salary_name': 'Overtime',
            'salary_type': 'Allowance',
            'salary_amount': 300,
        ],
        [
            'id': 4,
            'salary_name': 'Absence',
            'salary_type': 'Cut',
            'salary_amount': 100,
        ],
        [
            'id': 5,
            'salary_name': 'Tax',
            'salary_type': 'Cut',
            'salary_amount': 500,
        ]
    }
```

I've tried with code like this

```
<table width='100%' class='table-bordered'>
            <tr>
                <th align='left' colspan='2' width='50%'>Salary</th>
                <th align='left' colspan='2' width='50%'>Salary Cuts</th>
            </tr>
        foreach($salary->detil as $dg){
            <tr>
                if($dg->salary_type=='Allowance'){
                    <td>$dg->salary_name</td>
                    <td>$dg->salary_amount</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                } else{
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>$dg->salary_name</td>
                    <td>$dg->salary_amount</td>;
                }
            </tr>
        }
        </table>
```

this is the output:
[image]
I don't know how to combine these columns

Comment: What code do you already have? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please remember, we know nothing about your data. We can assume things that you forget to include, but that is dangerous, so please show examples of the data that support the required resulting table of data

Comment: @M1sterPl0w I code with PHP, I don't know, I haven't figured out the logic. what I've tried has become five rows data, where the allowance data on the left and on the right is empty.

Comment: @adhiskara please show your code. You cannot expect from the community they generate all the code for you.

Comment: @M1sterPl0w I've edited to include the code that I created. Is it possible to make the output that I want?

Comment: @adhiskara: I am not good in PHP, but is it possible to mix HTML and PHP-code like that ?

Comment: Loop your original array creating pairs of allowances and cuts, then loop the result printing the table rows

Comment: @Luuk it's possible except that the PHP code has to be enclosed inside PHP tags `<?php` and `?>`, which the code above either hasn't done or has omitted from the sample

Comment: @ADyson: OK, then nothing has changed.... I almost thought I had missed something.... 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filling an array for the table you want to print may be a good option here:

```
<table width='100%' class='table-bordered'>
<tr>
    <th align='left' colspan='2' width='50%'>Salary</th>
    <th align='left' colspan='2' width='50%'>Salary Cuts</th>
</tr>
<?php
    $sal=0;
    $salcuts=0;
    foreach($salary->detil as $dg){
        if($dg->salary_type=='Allowance'){
            $r[$sal][1] = $dg->salary_name;
            $r[$sal[[2] = $dg->salary_amount;
            $sal = $sal + 1;
        } else{
            $r[$salcuts][3] = $dg->salary_name;
            $r[$salcuts][4] = $dg->salary_amount;
            $salcuts = $salcuts + 1;
        }
    }
    for($x=0; $x<max($sal,$salcuts); $x++){
        echo "<tr>";
        for($c=1; $c<=4; $c++) {
            echo "<td>" . empty($r[$x][c])?"&nbsp;":$r[$x][c] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }        
                
?>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, its working and very usefull. now I understand the logic.